# How to add a GIF in Scene Builder Java FX

Tags: javafx, imageview, gif, scenebuilder

How can I introduce a GIF in JavaFx? Do I have to use ImageView to be able to add the GIF?

Comment: ImageView internally uses an [Image](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) which supports GIF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can add a .gif in an ImageView because .gif is an image file format. If the .gif file exists in the root directory of your project you can directly browse and set the file in the ImageView from scene builder.

Comment: I added the image from SceneBuilder to ImageView, but when I boot the program from NetBeans the static image appears and not in motion.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, the Gif works correctly, I had a problem with the builder and that's why it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
    @FXML
    private ImageView imageview;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
            Image i = new Image(new File("location/file.gif").toURI().toString());
            imageview.setImage(i);
    }
```

Worked for me.

Comment: for those having problems playing in jar, you can use this: `Image i = new Image(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/package/resource.gif"));`